# Proof with absolute value: sin squared less that absolute value of sin

Tags: analysis

I came upon this problem but I can't find a way to advance:

> Proof that $\sin^2x≤ |\sin  x|$

I already used trigonometric identities and the triangle inequality but got stuck.

Comment: $t^2\leq t$ for $0\leq t\leq1$

Answer (score 3):

Since $$\sin^2(x)=|\sin(x)||\sin(x)|\le |\sin(x)|\cdot 1$$